# Turning on bxSlider moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm using jQuery bxSlider. But the images are not moving in my slider. I want to turn on it.
Any one know about bxSlider? help me plz.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: false,
        pause: 4000,
        autoStart: true,
        autoDirection: 'next',
        autoHover: false,
        autoDelay: 0,
    });

});
</script>


<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <img src="images/slider/2849823img.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/slider/2849824img.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/slider/2849825img.jpg"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

best regards,

Comment: Show us your HTML which has images. You need HTML which contains ul with class .bxslider like this <ul class="bxslider">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the last comma in options object. That should do it.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            auto: true,
            pause: 4000,
            autoStart: true,
            autoDirection: 'next',
            autoHover: false,
            autoDelay: 0
//, <--remove this comma
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Plus each image should have its own li tag like this in HTML

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>        <img src="images/slider/2849823img.jpg"/> </li>
    <li>        <img src="images/slider/2849824img.jpg"/> </li>
    <li>        <img src="images/slider/2849825img.jpg"/> </li>

</ul>
```